# Preventing the change event which renders a view for a particular attribute in model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm rendering my view by listening to a model change, but I don't want to trigger or render the view when a particular value is changed in model.
this.options.model.on( 'change', this.render, this );

model.set(x: "hello");

I don't want render to be trigger when I set the model.

Comment: Set the model before you add the action listener.

Comment: I'm performing that action in initialize function

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't a lot of attributes in the model, then you can listen to the ones you care about:

```
// don't include change:x
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:a', this.render);
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:b', this.render);
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:c', this.render);
```

Or, you can add a check before rendering:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function (model, value, options) {
    if (model.changed.x === undefined) {
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a form for editing, where the values should prefill. So i'm populating data during render by calling change event on model as defaults are null. But one of the field i have to edit is in different modal/view, so when i edit and set it the view is rendering again and the previously edited values are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting the `silent` option when calling `model.set()`

```
model.set({ x: "hello" }, { silent: true });
```